# How to calculate number of days since the start of the year

Tags: java

Ex:The input is '03/10/2016' in 'MM/dd/yyyy'.  The total days is 69. Ensure you calculate leap year to find out if Feb has 28 days or 29 days.  in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Month;
    int Year;
    int Day;
    int cal = 0, num, Tot = 365;
    System.out.print("Please enter the Month");
    Month = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the Year");
    Year = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the Day");
    Day = input.nextInt();
    if (Month == 2) {
        if (Year % 4 == 0)
            num = 29;
        else
            num = 28;
    } else if (Month == 1 || Month == 3 || Month == 5 || Month == 7
            || Month == 8 || Month == 10 || Month == 12)
        num = 31;
    else
        num = 30;
    if (Tot != 365) {
        System.out.println("Not valid");
    } else {
        cal = Tot - Day;
        System.out.println("Remaining month of Days=" + cal);
    }

}
```

Comment: We aren't a code writing service or request machine. Ask a specific problem and we'll be glad to help

Comment: Try this `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);`.

Comment: Without using calender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several flaws:

1. The question asks for the number of days since start of the year. At the end you calculate and print out the remaining days until the end of the year. This is not the same.
2. To calculate the remaining days of the year you just subtract the entered day from the total of days of the year. You do nothing with the month. You should accumulate the days of all months which are already past.
3. If there is a leap year the total days of the year is 366 and not 365.
4. The check for a leap year is not exactly: The year 2000 was no leap year.

I have changed your code to reflect these points (I leave you with the exercise to check whether the entered day and month are valid):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DayOfYear {

    private static int[] MONTH_LENGTHS = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month;
        int year;
        int day;
        int remainingDays = 0, numDays = 0, totalDays = 365;
        System.out.println("Please enter the Month: ");
        month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Year: ");
        year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Day: ");
        day = input.nextInt();

        if (isLeapYear(year)) {
            totalDays++;
        }
        for (int iMonth = 1; iMonth < month; iMonth++) {
            numDays += MONTH_LENGTHS[iMonth];
            if (iMonth == 2 && isLeapYear(year)) {
                numDays++;
            }
        }
        numDays += day;

        remainingDays = totalDays - numDays;
        System.out.println("Number of days since start of the year = " + numDays);
        System.out.println("Remaining days of the year = " + remainingDays);

    }

    private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return year % 4 == 0 && year != 2000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir this program more helpful. This is perfect answer for me..,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] strings) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a month number: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();

        input.close();

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, Month.of(month), 01);
        int length = date.getMonth().length(false);

        System.out.print(Month.of(month).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL,
                Locale.US)
                + " " + year + " has " + length + " days");
    }
```